# After preview node is not saving the content.

Tags: entities

I added the data to node, after that i clicked on the preview button and it displaying preview of that node, but the problem is, node not saving the content. When i click the submit button it shows the **error message**

"The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form."

Please any one help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error that comes from the node module.

The error occurs when you submit the node form and the node has been changed by something since you loaded the form.

The change could be caused by another user editing the content, you editing it in a different tab/browser, some background task editing it, etc.

How it happens is:

1. You load the node edit form. The node object is pulled from the database at this time.
2. You make the changes.
3. You save the node.
4. The system checks the last changed date of the node object that was loaded when you loaded the edit form (in step 1) with the last changed date for that node directly in the database (the current last changed date).

It does this to stop two people changing a node at the same time, in which case one persons changes might accidentally override the other persons.

To get around the error, you have to refresh the node edit form and make your changes and save it again.

There is no way around it but there are ways to lessen the annoyance of getting to the end of an edit and being told you have to refresh.
One such way is the [content locking](https://drupal.org/project/content_lock) module.

That module makes it so that when you load a node edit page it "locks" that node, so if someone else goes to the edit page while you have it locked it will give them a warning and won't let them make edits until you have finished editing and the node is unlocked.

This means you won't waste time on an edit that you won't be able to save.

Comment: Nice explanation !!

Comment: No,another user is not there,it is in my local.Every time it happens like that.

Comment: You can't. It is a safeguard to stop problems from happening when a node is saved by two people at once. There are things that can ease the pain though. I have updated my answer to explain.

Comment: It doesn't have to be two human people. It could also be a node changing on cron or via rules or something like that. If you load the node edit page and anything updates that node before you click submit, that is when the error occurs. It works by checking the changed date of the node.